# Infinite loop while updating record

Tags: haskell, record

While running following code, I receive `file: <<loop>>` error.

My simplified code:

```
data KAutomat = KA
    { states :: Set.Set String
    , start :: KState
    , final :: Set.Set String
    , trans :: [Transition]
    , setW :: Set.Set (Set.Set String)
    , setP :: Set.Set (Set.Set String)
    } deriving (Eq,Show)

updateKa val p@(KA _ _ _ _ _ s) = p { setP = val}

anotherFunction ls ts a = do
    let valu = replaceNth (...etc...)
    let ts = updateKa (Set.fromList $ (map Set.fromList $ valu)) ts
```

And I got no idead what's wrong. Can someone help? I was trying debugging and it loops on the `updateKa val...` line.

Comment: `let ts = something ts` will always generate an infinite loop in Haskell.

Comment: One point of the record update syntax is that you don't to pattern match (which you would need to get and preserve the old values of the *other* fields); `updateKa val p = p { setP = val}` would be sufficient.

Comment: You probably just want `anotherFunction ls ts a = updateKa (...) ts`. You never actually update a value in Haskell; you just create a *new* value based on an old one and return it.

Comment: The `do` syntax is definitely wrong, since you aren't actually using a monad.

Comment: Turning on warnings points out the shadowed variable, hinting at a potential issue. Strongly recommended.